# Which Kernel version should I download to recompile my kernel with lock stats enabled

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-parameters

I'm trying to use the CLI tool `perf`, however it requires the `CONFIG_LOCKDEP` and `CONFIG_LOCK_STAT` enabled in the Kernel code.

I understand that to enable these flags, I need to download the source code of the kernel, edit the config, recompile it and reboot the machine.

However, I cannot understand which Kernel version I should download. Namely I have Ubuntu 22.04 with the kernel version `5.15.0-69-generic` running as a server. I tried downloading it from kernel.org. However overthere all kernel versions are numbered by three digits, while here my Kernel version has 4 digits.

I could not understand how Linux Kernel version numbers work. I also did not want to experiment to not break anything by installing wrong kernel version.

Could someone explain this, and maybe point me to a resource from where I can download a correct Kernel version.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should download the relevant Ubuntu kernel, and rebuild that:

```
apt source linux-image-unsigned-$(uname -r)
```

Follow [the instructions on the Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) to reconfigure and rebuild the kernel.